# Null Pointer Exception in Primavera P6 8.1

Tags: java, weblogic, primavera

I am getting a null pointer exception in a Primavera P6 8.1 installation. The exception only occurs in one section of the web-client: Application settings.P6 web and the P6 API are deployed on the same WebLogic (10.3.5) node running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 installation. I have done this installation using this same software stack a dozen times and don't have this issue on any of the other installs.

Exact error below:

```
Match: beginTraversal
Match: digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.6.0_20+, heap=-1--1, args=null, href=http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_17
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: null
    native platform is: Windows, x86 [ x86, 32bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.7 found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: true

    Match: ignoring maxHeap: -1
    Match: ignoring InitHeap: -1
    Match: digesting vmargs: null
    Match: digested vmargs: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: JVM args after accumulation: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: digest LaunchDesc: http://localhost:7001/p6/action/jnlp/appletsjnlp.jnlp?mainClass=com.primavera.pvapplets.adminpreferences.AdminPreferencesApplet&classPath=adminpreferences.jar,prm-applets-common.jar,forms-1.0.7.jar,prm-guisupport.jar,prm-to.jar,jide.jar,tablesupport.jar,formsupport.jar,applets-bo.jar,commons-lang.jar,prm-common.jar,resource_strings.jar,prm-img.jar,commons-logging.jar&name=AdminPreferences&version=8.1.2.0.0602
    Match: digest properties: []
    Match: JVM args: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: endTraversal ..
    Match: JVM args final: 
    Match: Running JREInfo Version    match: 1.7.0.17 == 1.7.0.17
     Match: Running JVM args match: have:<>  satisfy want:<>
Java Plug-in 10.17.2.02
Using JRE version 1.7.0_17-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\gwrichard
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This error is from the client and is not necessarily related to the deployment you just made, plus your error message doesn't actually show any errors. Check the client version to make sure it is correct, plus remove any duplicated JVMs on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the Java SE client installed on the client side machines. Versions of Java newer than 6_u32 don't seem to play well with P6 8.1. By uninstalling the Java client and accessing P6 web I was prompted to installed an ealier version of Java.

Once the earlier Java verion was installed full functionality to P6 web was available.